# Ckeditor 5 Ballon Block Edit Block Icon Change

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am new to CKeditor. Need help with Ckeditor 5. I am using Balloon Block. I need to change the Edit Block icon to my own custom icon. Please refer to the image attached. I am using Angular 8

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**The easiest way is to use webpack’s NormalModuleReplacementPlugin plugin. For example, to replace the bold icon use the following code in your webpack.config.js: **

```
plugins: [
new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
    /bold\.svg/,
    '/absolute/path/to/my/icon.svg'
)
```

]

Comment: what is the image name for the icon that I want to change.